# XPages: dijit.Tree dojo.xhrPost and Partial Refresh?

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib, dijit.tree

I have a `dijit.Tree` which works fine. Users can add, delete and rename nodes on [this tree (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ddev/rn7e3zfb/129/) if they have special authorization on it.

The next step is to post this changes back to the server, which works perfect, using `dojo.xhrPost` in conjunction with an `XAgent` (*instead of an XAgent this functionality could be achieved using extension library control for REST-Services of type `customRestService`. However, this is not available until domino version 9...*)

### Source code:

```xml
<xp:button value="Submit tree updates back to server " id="btnSubmit">
    <xp:this.onclick><![CDATA[dojo.xhrPost({
url: "folderService.xsp", // XAgent
handleAs: "json",
timeout: 1000,
postData: treeStore._getNewFileContentString(), // treeStore
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
load: function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        console.log("all folders saved " + data.success);
        dojo.byId("#{id:txtMessage}").innerHTML = data.message; ???
        dojo.removeClass("#{id:txtMessage}", "lotusHidden"); ???
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:wrapper}", {}); ???
    }
},
error: function() {
    dojo.byId("#{id:txtMessage}").innerHTML = 'Oops something goes wrong. The update on the folders weren\'t saved.'; ???
    dojo.removeClass("#{id:txtMessage}", "lotusHidden"); ???
    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:wrapper}", {}); ???
} 
});]]></xp:this.onclick>
</xp:button>
```

### Now the question:

I have the requirement to show some information to the user which comes back from the server (`load : function(data) {...}`).

### Possible solutions:

1. Do it only on client side (e.g. `dojo.byId("#{id:txtMessage}").innerHTML = data.message;`)?

> **Pros**: No partial refresh needed
>
> **Cons**: I can't work with already implemented custom controls (e.g. computed rendered property)

2. Do some partial refresh after a successfull `xhrPost`?
   If this is the right choice, how and were I should implement a partial refresh after a successfull xhrPost?

> My feeling says no, because why I should do a partial refresh only for the 
>   making information visible (e.g. rendered property...).

3. Do something else?

I am not sure which is the best approach to handle my requirements?

**Hint:** I am working on a Domino Sever 8.5.3 FP6

Thanks in advance for any answer.